# How to show numeric keybord when EditText is set to floating numbers?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-input-method, android-inputtype

I want to my phone to show numeric keyboard when I focus on an `EditText` which is set to `InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL`. But it shows alphanumeric (normal keyboard like whatsapp's) keyboard, How can I achieve this?

I use this to open keyboard:

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

I use this to set input type of `EditText`:

```
mEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
```

It's Dynamic. So I can't write it as XML attribute. User can switch input type with these two lines:
`mEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);` to get a floating number between 0 and 2.
`mEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);` to get any integer bigger or equal than 0.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

It is better to set **inputType in XML code**

Comment: You want to accept both Strings and Numeric values?

Comment: Then it is better to set it in XML code, which will give you numeric keyboard

Comment: It's Dynamic. So I can't write it as XML attribute. User can switch input type with these two lines: `mEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);` `mEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);`